# The SQL query succeeds, but does not make any changes to the table

Tags: sql

I have the following problem. I run this request, which passes successfully but it says "0 (rows affected)". In short, what I want to do. I'm trying to write a query that adds elements to the main table because I've linked Child tables I'm trying to retrieve the IDs and put them in the main table

```
INSERT INTO Articles
       ([ID],
        [ArtName],
        [ArtType],
        [SerNo],
        [MACNo],
        [UserID],
        [Available],
        [CityID],
        [StoreID],
        [WorkplaceID],
        [ItemPrice],
        [IP_01],
        [IP_02],
        [Note])
SELECT 
       (SELECT max([ID])+1 FROM Articles),
        'HP',
        art.ID,
        '123',
        'А18Н31',
        u.ID,
        av.ID,
        c.ID ,
        s.ID,
        w.ID,
        '14.23',
        '192.168.11.3',
        '192.168.11.3',
        GetDate()
        FROM Articles a
   INNER JOIN Workplace w ON a.WorkplaceID = w.ID
   INNER JOIN Store s ON a.StoreID = s.ID
   INNER JOIN City c ON a.CityID = c.ID
   INNER JOIN Avaiable av ON a.Available = av.ID
   INNER JOIN Users u ON a.UserID = u.ID
   INNER JOIN ArtType art ON a.ArtType = art.ID 
   WHERE c.CityName LIKE '%Sofia%' AND art.ArtTypeName LIKE '%FirstType%' AND s.StoreName LIKE '%First%' AND av.AvaiableName LIKE '%yes%' AND u.UserName LIKE '%Valq%' AND w.WorkplaceName LIKE '%FWorkplace%'
```

Comment: What database platform? What is the result of running just the select? Does the Articles table already have rows?

Comment: I use SSMS, table Аrticles already have rows as well as child tables. The elements I have chosen are written correctly

Comment: When executing only SELECT, it takes the necessary columns from the other tables and displays no column name for the main one

Answer (score 1):

This says "0 rows affected" because the `SELECT` returns no rows. This could be because nothing matches the `JOIN`s. This could be because the `WHERE` clause filters out all rows. Without sample data, there is no way to tell. You have to investigate yourself.

That said, this is highly suspicious:

```
(SELECT max([ID])+1 FROM Articles),
```

This is not the right way to have an incremental id in a table. You should be using an `identity` column. Or perhaps default to a sequence. In either case, the value of `id` would be set automatically when rows are inserted.

Also note that if this inserts multiple rows, all would get the same `id`, which is presumably not what you want.